# Best Way to Design a large table for use in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-design, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have posted a couple times regarding linked tables to display different results and a couple of very good people have helped me through.

but its starting to make me wonder am I designing my tables wrong to be running in to these problems.

for example I have 2 tables tblrunplan and tblplaces

tblrunplan has 20 visit fields (which could be repeated locations) each with a placeID number in
tblplaces has all the details for each place.

in my head that is normalised, is that correct?

if it is then when it comes to displaying the runplan information I obviously don't want to be displaying PlaceID numbers but there Place Names from the tblplaces.

how can I do that? without having 20 instances of tblplaces open with a join in each.

```
TBLPLACES:
PlaceID
Place Name
Lat
Long
Address 1
Address 2
Town
Contact Number

TBLRUNPLAN:
RunID
Visit1
Visit2
Visit3
Visit4
Visit5
Visit6
etc.
```

Comment: When you mention "repeatred locations", do you mean these are stored as rows, or columns?

Comment: no I mean the same place could be used multiple times in the same run plan

Comment: Can you post a sqlfiddle of the table schema? Might make it easier to understand it.

Comment: wouldn't let me post img of schema due to rep but added basic table structure

Comment: That is not a normalized scheme. You'd probably be best off adding a `Run` table (ID, date or something like that), and and intermediate table `RunPlan` (id, runid, placeid). That way you can visit any number of places during a run..

Comment: Sorry can you explain that I don't understand how its is not normalised. one place worth of details condensed to a ID number, that ID number is then used multiple times in other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, I'd replace the `TblRunPlan` wth a `Run` table (ID, date, extra data related to runs), and a new `RunPlace` table that serves as a way to record which places are visited on each run (id, RunID, PlaceID, VisitOrder).

This will ensure you have a flexible and extendable schema. The issue with the `RunPlan` table you have is that you have to reserve space for a set number (20) of places per run. Even if you might not visit 20 places every run, you still are consuming space for the storage.

Should you in the future decide to visit 25 or 15 places per run, you would not have to change a thing in the schema, whereas with your existing schema you would have to add or remove columns.

You can then retrieve information using something like the following:

```
SELECT
   R.RunID, R.date, RP.VisitOrder, P.Place_Name
FROM 
    Run R
    JOIN RunPlace RP ON R.RunID = RP.RunID
    JOIN Place P ON RP.PlaceID = P.PlaceID
```